# Return Back Php and MySQL Telegram Bot

Tags: php, mysql, telegram, telegram-bot

how do I get the user back by starting from $ stepUser 4

if it gets to the error "text" => $ errorPhotoAll?

I would like when it gets to else if ($ countPhoto> 2) and then gets it wrong, it returns to the beginning of this condition.

Moreover, when the user sends the photo as an Album, the messages in reply are as many as the photos. How can I send just one message here too?

```
elseif($stepUser == 4)
                {
                    $countPhoto = count($input->message->photo);
                    
                    if($countPhoto == 1)
                    {
                        $photoID = $input->message->photo[0]->file_id;
                        
                        
                        insertStepData($userID, 5, $photoID);
                        
                        $param = array(
                            "chat_id" => $chatID,
                            "parse_mode" => "HTML",
                            "text" => $step4
                        );

                        sendBot("sendMessage", $param);
                    }
                    else if ($countPhoto > 2)
                    {
                        $param = array(
                            "chat_id" => $chatID,
                            "parse_mode" => "HTML",
                            "text" => $errorPhotoAll
                        );
                        
                        sendBot("sendMessage", $param);
                    }
                    else {
                        $param = array(
                            "chat_id" => $chatID,
                            "parse_mode" => "HTML",
                            "text" => $errorPhoto
                        );
                        
                        sendBot("sendMessage", $param);
                    }
                }
```